# What to do if there are two contradicting answers?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, answers, asking-questions, advice

I got two seemingly good but contradicting answers to [this question about order in bases of vector spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065800/on-the-importance-of-order-for-bases-in-finite-dimensional-vector-spaces).

I don't know what to do because they both seem plausible and they do not agree.

What can I do to find out which of them is correct?

Comment: Distrust the two!

Comment: I suppose you could leave a comment under each answer asking how that answer aligns with the other one.

Comment: There's a recent similar (duplicate of this?) question.

Comment: ask a  more focused question. I do not see why anyone would need to know what you asked about, prior to multilinear algebra for differential forms.

Comment: @learner I've actually realized that Marc is absolutely correct here. I've deleted my answer and added a comment, I apologize if I have misled you in any way.

Comment: @neuguy Thank you for your comment. No reasons to apologise!

Comment: @neuguy but he is not!

Comment: What's with this weird comment^ by quid?

Comment: @learner see my comment on the answer on main. Why is the comment weird by the way?  It is a brief but firm response to "I've actually realized that Marc is absolutely correct here."

Comment: For the record: for the specific question, there was a detail I did not like about the answer, which is otherwise very good, and I feared it could cause confusion. This was cleared up in comments and via a minimal edit.  // Other than that my remarks are meant as  advice for the general situation.

Answer (score 19):

You have several options:

1. You can do your own research based on the information gained, to check what is correct and what is not correct.
2. You can ask the authors for further clarification, as recommended by Gerry Myerson.
3. You can consider circumstantial evidence to infer which of the two is more credible (author's reputation or score, the amount of details in the answer, references); this can however be very risky, especially the former two.
4. You can place a "bounty" to get more attention and other answers.

Likely I am forgetting some.